# PIP installing packages to wrong instance/directory of python

Tags: python, pip

I'm currently having an issue installing packages with PIP and I believe it is due to the fact that PIP is installing the packages to a directory created and used by Visual Studio, but I have another instance of Python installed in a different directory which is the one I'm using (in a different IDE), is there any way for me to change the directory in which PIP installs its packages to?

Comment: Usually, the packages are installed in the current directory that the project is in, assuming you have a virtual environement. If not, then pip will install the packages globally. Try using a virtual environment if you're not using one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and create the virtual environment within the project and then you can pip install your package around your project.

cd into your project directory and do;

for Mac OX or Linux

```
python3 -m venv <name of your env>
source <name of your env>/bin/activate
pip install your package name
```

or for windows;

```
python -m venv <name of your env>
.\<name of your env>\Scripts\activate
pip install your package name
```

It's not always good to install package globally as it will be conflicting with other packages.